# Missing Operating System When booting from USB drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I've been searching for hours and can't find a solution. I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with my Windows 10. I downloaded the iso and burned it to a USB drive, all good. Now when I select the USB as my boot option I get "Missing operating system..." and Windows 10 starts by default.

I've tried setting my configurations to UEFI and Legacy System... both didn't work. I've also disabled secure boot. I don't know what else I can do...

Before trying with Ubuntu I had tried with Mint Cinnamon and had the exact same issue... upto the same error message. What's the problem?

Comment: Try different tool to burn the OS to your USB drive (I suggest [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) they both work on Windows)

Comment: What tool did you use to create the USB? The [Ubuntu tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) suggests to use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

Comment: I've tried Universal USB Installer and usbootin... same issue with both... I'm trying Rufus now @singrium

Comment: Try a USB2 port instead of a USB3 port.